# Cuando ingreso la cantidad de discos vendidos por diferentes artistas, ¿como puedo hacer para que detecte quien vendió más?

Tags: java, scanner

```
package cantanteFamoso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListaCantantesFamosos extends cantanteFamoso   {


    public ListaCantantesFamosos(String nombre, String pais) {
        super(nombre, pais, discosVendidos);
        ArrayList<String> listaCantantesFamosos = new ArrayList<String>();

        listaCantantesFamosos.add(pais);
        listaCantantesFamosos.add(nombre);


    }
    public void lista(int n){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            System.out.println("ingrese nombre");
            String nombre=(String) teclado.nextLine();
            System.out.println("#"+i+" su nombre es "+nombre);
            System.out.println("ingrese pais");
            String pais=(String) teclado.nextLine();

            Discos listaCantantesFamosos=new Discos(generoMusica, nombreDisco, 0);
            System.out.println("genero musical");
            String generoMusical=(String) teclado.nextLine();
            System.out.println("nombre disco");
            String nombreDisco=(String) teclado.nextLine();
            System.out.println("numero discos vendidos");
            int discosVendidos=(int) teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.println("el pais de "+nombre+" es "+ pais+", que vendio "+ discosVendidos+"discos de nombre"+ nombreDisco);


        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos tengo la siguiente lista:

```
int[] listaDiscos = {10,40,70,80,90,20,70,150,400,600,900,800};
```

Para empezar asumiremos que el mayor es el primero y que consecuentemente su posición es la cero.

```
int mayor
mayor = listaDiscos[0];
```

recorreremos todo el array, por cada elemento del array que recorramos deberemos de preguntar si dicho elemento es mayor que el que tenemos almacenado.

```
    for (int x=1;x<listaDiscos.length;x++){
     if (listaDiscos[x]>mayor){
       mayor = listaDiscos[x];
     } 
    }
```

ahora tan solo tendras que mostrar el numero mayor(**mayor**) !!

Comment: y eso funciona con el scanner?